# 403 Forbidden - how to fix?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, apache2, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to access an PHP 7.x file on a **restricted webspace**, but get the famous `403`:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /path/to/file.php on this server.

After searching on StackOverflow and trying different settings, I set the **CHMOD** to `777`, which didn't change anything.

I've **no root nor apache access**.

Now I'm trying to allow access via `.htaccess`, but no success so far:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

Result: `500 - Internal Server Error`.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.htaccess` entries won't change the file permissions on the server. Have you tried setting the requested permissions to the directory where you want to save the uploaded file?

Comment: @NicoHaase  The file is already uploaded, `chmod` of file and folders set to `777`. It looks pretty unusual to me.

Comment: @NicoHaase looks like you are trying to hack something sorry we are not with you and if not then i can help you.

Comment: You _never_ need a file system permission of `0x777` for a php file execution triggered from a request to a http server. You only open security risks, huge ones.

Comment: If you get a "Permission denied" then there has to be a reason. You need to find that reason, then you can solve the issue. Two possible reasons which you have to check, we cannot do that for you: 1. some configuration in your http server denies the request, for example an authorization layer or 2. your http server process does not have access to the location of the file in the server side file system. For that remember that the process needs to be able to access the whole path heirarchy from the root of the file system up to the targeted file itself.

Comment: @THERAVI I don't hack anything. What do you mean by "we are not with you"?

Comment: @NicoHaase you are trying to access an PHP 7.x file on a restricted webspace what does it mean ? it means you don't have permission to access this webspace ..and in this case we are (SO members) not with you.

Comment: @arkascha I agree on avoiding `0x777` and thanks for your two advices. I'm gonna check it. :-)

Comment: @THERAVI I don't try to access anything, why do you think that?